# How to use w3c sitemap.xsd to validate w3c sitemap & google sitemap?

Tags: xml, xsd, sitemap, w3c

w3c sitemap.xsd: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
It looks like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" targetNamespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

I have two sitemap file.
1. w3c sitmap file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://t.qq.com/p/t/42509089158929/</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

2.google-sitemap file, like this：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
<url>
<loc>http://blog.ifeng.com/article/11487489.html</loc>
<lastmod>2011-05-23T09:33:01+08:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I use w3c sitemap.xsd to validate these two files by xmllint.
1. w3c stitemap file, normal and success
2. google-sitemap file, output like below

```
$ xmllint --schema sitemap.xsd sitemap_google.xml  --noout 
sitemap_google.xml:2: element urlset: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9}urlset': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
sitemap_google.xml fails to validate
```

I think, the problem is the namespace is different in google-sitemap.xml and sitemap.xsd.
How should I do to use sitemap.xsd to validate these two sitemap file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reference to the sitemaps.org sitemap schema in the google sitemap instance document then I don't see how you are supposed to validate it or even why you would want to.

By including the namespace at the top of the file, the google sitemap instance is clearly stating that it is an instance of the google.com sitemap schema and not the sitemaps.org sitemap schema.

Comment: The body of each file are totally same.  A sitemap file include <urlset> <url> ... and such tags, I want to validate these files by one xsd(schema) file, but I failed to do this. If I remove  xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9" in google sitemap file, the validate will pass.

Comment: Regardless of the body of the file, the namespace attribute defines where the types in your xml are defined. If you want to validate a file which declares it's types as being defined in schemaA, but using schemaB, it will not work.

Comment: oh, so bad. I want to validate theses xml ignore their namespace declaration, Do you have any idea? I use xerces-c lib.